# Seahorse (Passwords and Keys) - how to mark key as trusted

Tags: 22.04, ssh, keyrings, seahorse, ssh-agent

I have these 2 OpenSSH keys in Seahorse (Passwords and Keys),
but the first one (that only has the golden key icon) is somehow not marked as trusted nor personal and is only displayed when I choose "Show any".

I got the key there by running `ssh-add path/to/key` and then `sudo service ssh restart`, because when I tried to import it directly through Seahorse I got the message "Reason: Unrecognized or unsupported data.".

I also tried restarting Seahorse, but the key still doesn't seem to be in the trusted category.

Another interesting thing I've noticed in the list is that the other key (the one with both silver and golden key icon) has key filename there and "Personal SSH key" on the right and also appears in the "Show trusted" list. But the non-trusted key has "other_keys.seahorse" and is marked as just "SSH key".

Is there a way how to mark they key "personal" and/or "trusted" so it appears in the proper lists in the Seahorse?

(I am not against some terminal/cmd work if needed...)

[image: seahorse icons and menu]